# Как в PHP-MyAdmin экспортировать БД для Postgres?

Tags: mysql, postgresql

Экспорт делаю из PHPMyAdmin на локальном компьютере c OpenServer 5.3.7 из БД MySQL, а импортирую через Adminer на докер с БД Postgres.
Сделал экспорт БД в файл **init.sql**, и тут случилось интересное - в БД MySQL он прекрасно импортируется(и на локальную машину и в докер с MySQL), а в БД Postgress - нет. Сообщает об ошибке:

> ERROR: unrecognized configuration parameter "sql_mode"

Поковырял инет, там написано, что синтаксис у баз разный, поэтому и не импортируется. Может надо какие-то настройки указать в импорте или не туда копаю?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дохлый номер. Синтаксисы MySQL и PostgreSQL совместимы ну очень чуть-чуть. Некоторые конструкции так и вовсе непереносимы и потребуют полного переписывания.

Рекомендую следующую последовательность действий.

1. Экспорт из MySQL только структуры, без данных.
2. Редактирование дампа вручную, адаптация синтаксиса под PostgreSQL.
3. Загрузка дампа в PostgreSQL и проверка созданной структуры. При необходимости ручная рихтовка.
4. Экспорт из MySQL только данных в файлы CSV (каждая таблица в отдельный файл, запросы SELECT INTO OUTFILE).
5. Загрузка данных в таблицы PostgreSQL (каждая таблица отдельно, запросы COPY FROM).

Comment: Спасибо! Решил конечно проблему чуток по другому, но Вы меня натолкнули на правильный путь. Во-общем, т.к. в компосе у меня не только Postgres, но и app есть (в котором прописано создание таблиц), то я просто изменил компос и открыл временно порт на внешку. К этому порту я подцепился через DataGrip и сделал копирование данных таблиц (т.к. csv не хотел принимать, решил реализовать через DataGrip)

Comment: @Алексей Ну в любом случае - данные, как правило, совместимы (могут возникнуть фортели с литералами дат, например) и без особых проблем переносятся напрямую, а вот структура, особенно когда дело дойдёт до функций/триггеров/прочего - увы...

Answer (score 0):

Да, возможно проблема связана с тем, что синтаксис SQL-запросов и настройки `БД MySQL` и `PostgreSQL` различаются, и некоторые команды, поддерживаемые в MySQL, могут не поддерживаться в PostgreSQL. В данном случае, ошибка связана с тем, что параметр `"sql_mode"`, который присутствует в экспортируемом файле для MySQL, не является параметром конфигурации для `PostgreSQL`.

Возможно, стоит попробовать экспортировать данные из MySQL с использованием другого инструмента, который поддерживает экспорт в PostgreSQL, например, `pgloader` или `talend`. Эти инструменты автоматически конвертируют SQL-запросы, созданные для MySQL, в соответствующий синтаксис PostgreSQL, что может помочь избежать ошибок при импорте.

Если использование других инструментов не подходит, можно попробовать вручную изменить экспортируемый файл `init.sql`, заменив команды, не поддерживаемые PostgreSQL, на соответствующие команды, поддерживаемые в PostgreSQL. Также стоит обратить внимание на использование типов данных и функций, поскольку они также могут отличаться в MySQL и PostgreSQL.

Наконец, при импорте в PostgreSQL можно попробовать использовать опцию `--no-sequences`, чтобы избежать ошибок, связанных с использованием последовательностей в MySQL, которые не поддерживаются в PostgreSQL. команда импорта может выглядеть так:

```
psql -U username -d dbname -f init.sql --no-sequences
```

Comment: Это где вводить - в PowerShell?

Comment: @Алексей Да, только не забудьте перейти в католог где лежит `init.sql`.  нужно убедиться, что PostgreSQL установлен и настроен на вашем компьютере. Также убедитесь, что у вас есть права на импорт данных в PostgreSQL.

Comment: А через DataGrip нельзя реализовать такой экспорт?

Comment: Может, какие конвертеры есть? А то получается, что надо будет ставить Postgres на машину...